# Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi HD: No sound

Tags: windows-7, audio, thinkpad, sound-card, creative

I'm using Windows 7 with the latest updates. Now I got a Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi HD and I wanted to test it. I connected my sound system (Edifier S730D) with the external audio interface via Cinch cable and the notebook (Lenovo W510) with the external audio interface via USB. Windows installed the default USB audio driver and it should work out of the box without installing additional drivers/software (as the manual states).

I selected the USB Soundblaster HD as default playback device. I can see the bar moving but I get no sound. I have chosen the right channel on my sound system but I get no sound. The volume is on the highest level.

I also tried to use the earphone output of the Soundblaster HD, but I get also no sound.

What is wrong or what do I have to change to hear the sound?

Answer (score 0):

A look under playback devices showed me a new entry "Speakers - USB Sound Blaster HD". Before I had selected "Digital Audiointerface - USB Sound Blaster HD".